# Testing 2checkout intigration for demo sales

Tags: ruby, payment-gateway, 2checkout

While testing 2checkout integration on demo sales what will be the return value of  parameter **credit_card_processed**. It will be Y or N

Answer (score 0):

The credit_card_processed parameter on demo sales should return Y if successful, or N if non-successful.

If you look at the very bottom of https://www.2checkout.com/documentation/checkout/parameters you'll see as long as the response is 'Approved' the value of 'Y' will be returned.